# How to inject html to every page with a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

I would like to write a plugin which injects specific content to every non admin page. This is my first plugin.

I've figured out how can I inject content to every non admin page's head:

```
<?php
    function myfunction() {
?>
<!-- My injected content.... -->
....
<?php
}

if (!is_admin()) {
  add_action('wp_head', 'myfunction');
}
```

Unfortunately I can not figure out how to inject to the body, say an  element, because I did not find the appropriate action.

- Injecting a script to head, which injects elements to DOM is not a solution  this case, because the injected content must be there at load time, so it may be late to modify the DOM after load.
- The injected content must be "calculated" and the only place it can be calculated is php serverside.

Comment: You may want to take a look at the WordPress `the_content` filter https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_content/

Comment: does the injected html depend of the body content or it can be calculated before the generation of the body ?

Comment: @mmm: It does not depend on the body content

Comment: why not use `wp_footer` instead of `wp_head`, that is inside the body at the bottom of the page. if it is just for a script and you don't care where the content outputs that would be ideal.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `is_page()` function or `is_single()` function to echo content to front end pages

```
function add_content_to_page {

if ( is_page() ) {
echo '<p>content</p>';
 }   
}
```

or combine the two :

```
function add_content_to_page {

if ( is_page() || is_single() ) {
echo '<p>content</p>';
 }   
}
```

Similarly you can do `is_page(41)` to target a specific page id
or `is_home() || is_front_page()` to target the homepage alone
there a lot more options and examples in the [WordPress codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/)

Comment: This is no way answers the question asked.